# iOS App rejected because of Braintree Payment gateway integration for selling Digital content

Tags: paypal, in-app-purchase

My app is posting jobs.
User can post his jobs by paying some amount for each job.
And If he subscribes for monthly, he can post unlimited jobs.
   We can do monthly subscriptions using In App Purchase. My question is how to charge user for each job he posts with out Monthly subscription.

I have implemented it by using Paypal integration. Apple rejected by stating that, Digital content can't be sold using third party payment gateways. Go for In App Purchase.

How to implement it by using In App Purchase. What kind of subscription I can go for to charge the user each time he posts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can charge your user a fixed amount or let them pay a one-time fee for unlimited??

Comment: I would like to provide two options. i) Charge each time he posts a job, ii) Monthly once.